# Issue with Tensorboard and nothing logging

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, hyperparameters

I was following google's tensorboard tutorial with hparams [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams). However, when I try to implement that in my own model, nothing is showing in the logs. The main difference is that I used an Image Data Generator, but I do not see how that would affect the hyperparameters. I have included all the code used to get the hyperparameters, but removed the model and basic packages I imported for ease.

```
# Load the TensorBoard notebook
%load_ext tensorboard
# Clear all logs
!rm -rf ./logs/
```

Here is what I have set up for the hyperparameters. Just learning rate and weight decay. Slightly augmented from the tutorial, but largely very much the same style.

```
HP_lr = hp.HParam('learning_rate', hp.Discrete([3, 4, 5]))
HP_weight_decay= hp.HParam('l2_weight_decay', hp.Discrete([4, 5, 6]))
METRIC_ACCURACY = 'accuracy'
```

This is a little different to account for the values above, but those are simply variable names

```
# file writer
with tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/hparam_tuning').as_default():
  hp.hparams_config(
    hparams=[HP_lr, HP_weight_decay],
    metrics=[hp.Metric(METRIC_ACCURACY, display_name='Accuracy')],
  )
```

I have a function that builds the model taking an hparams argument. Besides using datagen.flow() in the model.fit, nothing changes.

```
def train_test_model(hparams):
  model = build_model(hparams)
  model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64),
                    epochs=1,verbose=0)
  _, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,batch_size=64, verbose = 1)
  return accuracy

# For each run log the metrics and hyperparameters used
def run(run_dir, hparams):
  with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
    hp.hparams(hparams)  # record the values used in this trial
    accuracy = train_test_model(hparams)
    tf.summary.scalar(METRIC_ACCURACY, accuracy, step=1)
```

Sets up the dictionary to be used by hp

```
session_num = 0
for learn_rate in HP_lr.domain.values:
  for wd in HP_weight_decay.domain.values:
      hparams = {
          HP_lr: 1*10**(-learn_rate), # transform to something like 1e-3
          HP_weight_decay: 1*10**(-wd)
      }
      run_name = "run-%d" % session_num
      print('--- Starting trial: %s' % run_name)
      print({h.name: hparams[h] for h in hparams})
      run('logs/hparam_tuning/' + run_name, hparams)
      session_num += 1

%tensorboard --logdir logs/hparam_tuning
```

Comment: Hi , did you get the solution ?